# openai api Chat completions response format

Tags: http, request, openai-api

```
const axios = require("axios");
require("dotenv").config();
const connection2 = require("../configs/db-connection.js").connection2;

const apiKey = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;



async function generateTweets(article, keywords, numberOfTweets ,callback) {
    try {
        article = article.replace(/\t|\n/g, "");
        numberOfTweets = parseInt(numberOfTweets);

        const prompt = `기사:${article}\n키워드:${keywords.join(
            ","
        )}\nGenerate a tweet about the article and keywords up to 140 characters`;

        const data = {
            prompt,
            max_tokens: 280, // 트윗의 최대 길이를 280으로 설정
            n: numberOfTweets,
        };

        console.log("processed data :", data);
        // OpenAI API 호출
        const response = await axios.post(
            "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/text-davinci-003/completions",
            data,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
                },
            }
        );

        // API 응답에서 생성된 트윗들 추출
        const tweets = response.data.choices.map((tweet) => tweet.text.trim());

    if (callback) {
      callback(tweets.length);
      saveTweetLengthToDatabase(tweets.length); // 이 부분을 추가합니다.
    }

        return tweets;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("OpenAI API 호출 중 오류 발생:", error.message);
        return null;
    }
}

// 트윗 생성 함수 실행
// generateTweets(article, keywords, numberOfTweets)
//  .then((tweets) => {
//      if (tweets && tweets.length > 0) {
//          console.log("생성된 트윗들:");
//          tweets.forEach((tweet, index) => {
//              console.log(`${index + 1}. ${tweet}\n`);
//          });
//      } else {
//          console.log("트윗을 생성할 수 없습니다.");
//      }
//  })
//  .catch((error) => {
//      console.error("트윗 생성 중 오류 발생:", error);
//  });

async function insertArticle(article, keywords, tweets) {
    try {
    var complete= false;
    
        for (const tweet of tweets) {
            await connection2.query(
                "insert into login.article (content, created_dt) values (?, ?)",
                [tweet, new Date()]
            );
        }
    
        console.log("article 저장 완");
    const saveArticleLog = (complete) => {
      complete = true;
    };

    return complete;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("데이터베이스 insert 오류 :", error.message);
    }
}

//기호꺼
async function saveTweetLengthToDatabase(tweetLength) {
  try {
    await connection2.query(
      "INSERT INTO login.article (count) VALUES (?)",
      [tweetLength]
    );
    console.log("트윗 길이를 DB에 저장했습니다.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("DB에 트윗 길이 저장 오류:", error.message);
  }
}

module.exports = { generateTweets, insertArticle, saveTweetLengthToDatabase };
```

How do I get a message inside the program that I have completed all the posts I requested in the OpenAI API??
We are working on a project with nodejs now. One problem is that if you finish writing what we requested in gpt, it will show in the history that you are done and if you haven't finished writing yet, it will show that it is in progress, but since I make it using hbs files, I have to deal with this grammar only through each and if. Please help me if anyone knows

Originally, I tried to find the length of tweets and enter it in db, and compare it to the number of text generated by the user, but there are many errors